# difference between returning true and false statements at the end in a boolean method Java

Tags: java, methods, return, boolean, comparison

Good day. I got a slight confusion with the true\false return calls in a boolean method.
So the code is :

```
public class CheckOut {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] m = new int[3][3];
        int[][] m1 = new int[m.length][m[0].length];
        System.out.println("Enter the nums for the first matrix : ");
        getM(m);
        System.out.println("Enter the nums for the second matrix : ");
        getM(m1);
        System.out.println(strictlyIdentical(m, m1));

    }

    static int[][] getM(int[][] m) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) {
                m[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }
        return m;
    }

    static boolean strictlyIdentical(int[][] m, int[][] b) {

        if (m.length != b.length && m[0].length != b[0].length) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) {
                if (m[i][j] != b[i][j]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The above method works totally fine and returns true if two matrices are identical but
why when I compare the values on their correctness and return true if the vals in the if statements are correct and return false at the end i don't get the desired output .(it is literally true for any entered nums)
**Consider this:**

```
    static boolean strictlyIdentical(int[][] m, int[][] b) {

        if (m.length == b.length && m[0].length == b[0].length) {
            return true;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) {
                if (m[i][j] == b[i][j]) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now I'm comparing the values on their similarity not difference , if i can say so...
And the output of this code if given the following input is as follows:

```
Enter the nums for the first matrix : 
12 3 4 3 2 1 2 3 3
Enter the nums for the second matrix : 
1 2 3 2 3 2 1 2 3 
true
```

So the preceding method returns true whereas the nums are apparently different.
But the logic didn't change in my opinion...
 is there a certain rule that dictates the order of return statements?
 or is there a logic issue in my code?

Comment: You simply cannot swap true and false and expect the same result. The first implementation is correct because it says: `if there is at least one index containing different elements, then the arrays are not equal.`

The second implementation is not correct because it says that `if there is at least one index containing the same elements, then the arrays are equal` which is obviously not what you want

Answer (score 2):

So im not sure if you just looked at your code too long and didnt see this little line of code, but it always return true because of the first if statement.

```
    static boolean strictlyIdentical(int[][] m, int[][] b) {

    if (m.length == b.length && m[0].length == b[0].length) {
        return true;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) {
            if (m[i][j] == b[i][j]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The first if statement will always return true if the lengths are equal. The example you gave had matrices with the same length, and therefore returned true.
EDIT*****
Your for statement also will return true on the FIRST match between the matrices. Lookinbg at the if statement, the first index where the 2 matrices are equal, the return causes the code to break out of the function and return true, not considering other cases after the first similarity. After any return statement is called, the function is abandoned and will no longer do any code after the return statement is called.

Comment: But even emitting this line doesn't solve the problem

Comment: I tried to implement the code without the first comparison and it still returns true for any  given nums

Comment: @vm_1_r You're returning true on the first match instead of going through the entire thing. There is a huge difference in the logic there.

Comment: Here is the output of the second (problematic)case without first if

Comment: Enter the nums for the first matrix : 
1 2 3 2 1 3 2 1 1
Enter the nums for the second matrix : 
1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
true

Comment: I deleted the first if

Comment: Please reread my post and the edit, itll answer the second part of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The second implementation definitely has a logic error. The difference is that the first will return `false` if any two elements are not equal while the second will return `true` as soon as **any** two elements are equal, not to mention, the first check is also wrong as JakeTheSnake indicated.

Obviously, in your case, you have to go through every position in both matrices and be sure that each is equal - that's why the the first implementation works, and the second does not.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `return` inside a method, it automatically ends the execution of that method.
So think about it, at the first two lines you tell your method to return true if only the sizes of the two matrices are identical. So in the example you gave, it's enough that the two matrices are the same size to get true.
The same thing happens when you get to the for loops afterward, it is enough to have one identical value at the same index to return true.
This is why you should check whether they are **not** identical, and then return false. And only if they "passed" all examinations, then you can return true.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but try to run this code with the first if statement and enter more than 9 values 12 f.e. and do the same thing in the second case the output will still be true...

Comment: Even though the first if stements "checks" for the length... you can even have 12 elements in the first matrix and 20 in the second the output will be true

Comment: Enter the nums for the first matrix : 
1 2 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 2 3
Enter the nums for the second matrix : 
1 2 3 23  23 2 32 32 3 23 2 32 3 23 23 2 3 23 23 2
true

Comment: Again, even if the first value in each one is identical, the method returns true. In this example, the method will return true because both matrices have 1 at their first index. So when your method will get there, it will return true and won't check the other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your piece of code can't work for many reasons, e.g. why does your function return `True` if the matrices have the same amount of row and the first rows have the same amount of values?

```
 if (m.length == b.length && m[0].length == b[0].length) {
            return true;
 }
```

**You don't check the values inside the rows!**

By the way I write down my solution, try this and if you have questions I'm here to respond.

```
    static boolean strictlyIdentical(int[][] m, int[][] b) {

    // Check if both matrices have the same amount of row, if not then return false
    if (m.length == b.length) {
        // If yes save that number
        int rowAmount = m.length;
        // Start control the i-th row
        for (int i = 0; i < rowAmount; i++) {
            // Check if the i-th row of both matrices have the same amount of values, if not then return false
            if(m[i].length != b[i].length) return false;
            // If yes save that number
            int rowLength = m[i].length;
            // Check if values are equal, if not then return false
            for (int j = 0; j < rowLength; j++) {
                if (!(m[i][j] == b[i][j])) return false;
            }
        }
        // Matrices passed all controls, they are IDENTICAL
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

Comment: Thanks ... I agree with the irrelevancy of the first if stements in my code but even though it mocks to be checking the inputted value it DOESN'T ...

Comment: Try to enter more than 9 values in the first matrix let's say 11

Comment: and more or less than eleven in the second the output will be true nevertheless

Comment: for instance Enter the nums for the first matrix : 
12 12 12 12 1 32 323 3 12 12 12 1 212 12 12123232
Enter the nums for the second matrix : 
21212 23 23 24 343 4 54 54 6 456 5 65 76 7 676 767 
true

Comment: the output is true

Comment: It doesn't return True. Try my code by yourself...
OUTPUT: https://i.imgur.com/dOn59aY.png

Comment: I was talking about my code with the first if statement in the strictlyIdentical method

Comment: Why does it return true everywhere when it is supposed to return false since the inputted Values differ by length

Comment: if(m.length==b.length&&m[0].length==b[0].length)